# Which JS library is used in Jira Workflow Designer? Looking for library for drawing dependencies on schemas

Tags: javascript, dependencies, workflow, jira

I'm looking for the JS library similar to the one used in Jira Workflow editor (example below).

[image: JIRA Workflow]

I need to visualize dependencies between elements and probably(in the future) make it configurable by mouse (with drag'n'drop).

P.S. I've tried to detect name of this library within the Developer Console, but had no luck (probably it's Atlassian proprietary library).
If you have Jira you can explore it yourself: Project -> Administration -> Workflows

Comment: Besides the fact that your question looks off-topic: what has this got to do with UML?

Comment: I suppose UML diagrams could be depicted by the same library, btw why do you think it's off-topic?

Comment: Because SO is not Google. Your question is not UML-related at all, only because you want to draw something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After looking at the JS source for the Workflow Designer in Atlassian JIRA in the console, it seems to be using a mixture of Atlassian developed code and a whole host of other libraries.

However, the drawing part at least seems to be extending functionality provided by [Draw2D JS](https://github.com/freegroup/draw2d) library. Another option for what you want to achieve could be [Raphael JS](http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/) which is also a JS drawing library.